# Bearded dragon sick or gravid?

Tags: behavior, health, reptiles, bearded-dragon

I have had my bearded dragon for almost a year, and I got her when she was a baby. She has always been very nice and never seemed agitated toward anyone. About a week ago I thought she had infertile eggs. She just got out of brumation. But she seems to be acting funny lately.

She has all the symptoms of having infertile eggs. She has been eating more, runs around her cage, and she has started to dig. I made a box for her to lay her eggs in but doesn't seem interested. Now when I go to pick her up she doesn't seem to want to come out of her cage. Now whenever I pet between her eyes she will kick me with her back legs!

She looks white like she's going to shed, but she has still never been this way with me before. Also when I can manage to get her out of her cage without a fuss she will randomly bolt away like under beds or just away from me. I'm worried about her. And I just want to make sure she's okay. She seems to be Always hungry. I haven't changed anything lately.

Could she just be stressed? Is she getting aggressive because of the eggs or is she sick and doesn't have eggs at all?
[image]

Comment: Is she caged with a male? Have you been trying to breed? If so when was she introduced to the male? When were they separated? Can you take a pic of her abdomen and edit your question to show what her belly looks like?

Comment: Can you tell me about her setup?

Comment: Bearded dragons can become aggressive whenever they are shedding. Wait a little longer and if she starts to have light dull spots she is shedding. Also do you know if it is a girl for sure?